# What is the necessary condition on $f$ such that the DE $dy/dx=f(y)$ has a solution?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity

In my book, it is written that we shall assume throughout the discussion that follows that $f$ and its derivative $f'$ are continuous functions of $y$ on some interval $I$.

I am guessing that this assumption is made in order that the autonomous DE $dy/dx=f(y)$ has a solution. However, I feel like the continuity of $f$ is enough to guarantee that the DE has a solution since this would imply that $dy/dx$ is continuous on some $I$. What am I missing?

Comment: This is somewhat similar to the question about the necessary condition for the absolute convergence of a series. It does not exist, the boundary between converging and diverging series is rather soft. Here continuity is not a necessary condition for local existence, only a sufficient one. And the Lipschitz condition is a weaker sufficient condition for uniqueness than the continuous differentiability, but still not a necessary one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Continuity of $f'$ guarantees uniqueness of solution $\begin{cases} \frac{dy}{dx} = f(y) \\ y(x_0) = y_0\end{cases}$, take a look at [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem). However, only continuity of $f$ guarantees only existence of solution, not uniqueness; it is [Peano theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_existence_theorem).

For example, consider problem $\begin{cases} \frac{dy}{dx} = 2\sqrt{y} \\ y(0) = 0\end{cases}$. It has two solutions $y = 0$ and $y = x^2$, because $f(y) = 2\sqrt{y}$ is continuous near zero and $f'(y)$ isn't. However, $\begin{cases} \frac{dy}{dx} = 2\sqrt{y} \\ y(1) = 1\end{cases}$ has unique solution $y = x^2$, at least in some neighbourhood of $(x = 1, y=1)$.

Comment: Remark: One could say that the second example does not fall into the discussed core of ODE theory as the domain $y\ge0$ is not open. And removing the boundary removes the interesting part of the situation. However, this can be changed without changing the discussed solutions by using a form that is defined everywhere such as $y'=2\sqrt{|y|}$ or $y'=2{\rm sign}(y)\sqrt{|y|}$ or $y'=2\sqrt{\max(0,y)}$ or ...